# ISO 8583 - How are BCD Values Calculated For Fields With Subfields?

Tags: iso, bcd, iso8583

Can anyone answer how BCD data is usually calculated for fields what have subfield values?

I don't mean in terms of code, as I have that part nailed down.

What I mean is say I have field X, which is to be sent containing data for 5 sub values. The field is BCD, but would each sub-value be converted to BCD and then appended to field X or would they be added to field X in the clear and then converted as a whole to BCD?

Can't find a clear answer anywhere... not even in the message spec I'm working off of oO

Cheers,
Mike K

Comment: If I understand your question then you are saying that the message spec does not include the format for the subfield values. If so, it might help to  remember that the subfields have to be formatted in such as way as to allow the receiver to parse them. The receiver must be able to know when one field ends and the following field begins.

Comment: The enclosing field is not BCD. The subfields are BCD. The enclosing field is just a sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know the format of field X and the format of subfields.
Let me give you an example.

Assuming that you would like to transmit emv data form pos to Host using a field X.
A format for field X is described below.

> Length Attribute 3 bytes LLL Length of data to follow
> Subfield 1 var bytes First Additional subfield
> Subfield 2 var bytes Second Additional subfield
> ...
> Subfield n var bytes nth Additional subfield
>
> The structure of each additional subfield is as follows
> Tag Name     2 bytes
> Tag Length   1 byte
> Tag Value    ..bytes

Answer (score 0):

If a field contains subfields, then every subfield is packed or unpacked with its own format.

The subfields should then not be packed or unpacked again.

If a field contains subfields, it is unnecessary to define the format of the field body. However, the field header format (tag or length) can be defined.

The following example contains a field with three subfields

```
Message Structure:
<f type="VAL" name="Parent" len="21">
    <f type="VAL" name="Child1" bodyPacker="BcdBodyPacker" len="6"/>
    <f type="VAL" name="Child2" bodyPacker="BcdBodyPacker" len="7"/>
    <f type="VAL" name="Child3" bodyPacker="BcdBodyPacker" len="8"/>
</f>

Message data:
<f name="Parent">
    <f name="Child1" val="111111111111"/>
    <f name="Child2" val="22222222222222"/>
    <f name="Child3" val="3333333333333333"/>
</f>

Message bytes in hex:
111111111111222222222222223333333333333333
```

The source code of the example can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/credibledoc/credible-doc/blob/master/iso-8583-packer/src/test/java/com/credibledoc/iso8583packer/examples/StackOverflow33957342Test.java)

The [iso-8583-packer](https://github.com/credibledoc/credible-doc/tree/master/iso-8583-packer) Java library was used for creation of this example. I am the author of the library.